# How to make Vim ignore file extensions when opening files through the command line/shell?

Tags: vim

Consider the following directory tree:

```
root/include/file.hpp
root/source/file.cpp
root/images/file.png
```

The command line is inside the directory `root`.

In the `vimrc` file, there is `set wildignore=*.png`.

If you open Vim in the folder `root` and run `:next */file.*`, it opens only `file.hpp` and `file.cpp`.

However, if you launch Vim from command line with `vim */file.*`, it opens all three files.

So, when feeding it a filename, it first loads the files, then `vimrc`? Is there a way to ignore extensions when opening files with Vim through the command line? Or to make Vim load `vimrc` first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first scenario, the glob expansion is done by Vim and thus obeys the rules in your `vimrc`.

In the second scenario, the glob expansion is done by your shell and there's no reason to expect it to obey the rules in your `vimrc`.

You can do something like `$ vim -c "next */file.*"`, which essentially opens Vim without a filename and executes `next */file.*`.

Or you can exclude the pattern directly in your shell. Assuming you have `extglob` set, this can be done in bash with `$ vim !(file.png)`.

Comment: Oh, that explains it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

When doing `:next */file.*` from within Vim, vim expands the wildcard and filters by wildignore. When doing `vim */file.*` from your shell, the shell expands the wildcard, and passes all three files to Vim.

Depending on your shell, this will probably work instead:

```
vim +"args */file.*"
```